# How do I use ajax to load a PHP file with a PHP variable

Tags: php, ajax

I want to use this:

```
$("#content").load("/path/include.php");
```

to load a php include, but I need to use the js function to update a variable first..

In plain PHP this would look like:

```
 <?php $variable = 'variable'; include(/path/include.php); ?>
```

How do I update that variable before including the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AJAX to load the second script, passing a parameter containing the JavaScript value:

```
$("#content").load("/path/caller.php", {param: 'something'});
```

caller.php:

```
<?php
$variable = $_POST['param'];
include('/path/include.php');
```

Comment: Really nice solution!